# Similar to market exchanging or trading program c++

Tags: c++

i'm trying to complete my program for a while already and i have came to the part where everything compiles but crashes immediately. My task is to make a similar CD exchange program where people may ask for particular CD or put up on a bid particular CD, information is read from a file and separation is looking like this: 
Time Action Personal_ID CDname (For Example: 100 A 11111111111 ACDC) Where

```
Time = Time when offer is put, integers
Action = A or B, where A - Ask, B - Bid, char
Personal_ID = Personal identification code length of 11 integers
CDname = name of CD asked of bid
```

All information is already put and read from file. My use of libraries is limited. 
So mainly my task is to read information from input file, sort the list and search for match where A(asker) and B(bidder) wants the same CD and in output file write all the matches in format `(Time(when deal made, so latest) Personal_ID(of asker) Personal_ID(of bider))`

```
Like example input: 
10 A 1111111 ACDC
33 B 2222222 ACDC
Output:
33 1111111 2222222
```

My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class elem
{
public:
    unsigned long int time;
    char action;
    char PIcode[12];
    char CDname[51];
    elem * next;

    elem(unsigned long int, char, char [12],char [51]);

};
elem::elem(unsigned long int time2,char action2, char PIcode2[12],char CDname2[51])
{
    time=time2;
    action=action2;
    strcpy(PIcode,PIcode2);
    strcpy(CDname,CDname2);
    next=NULL;
}
class List{
public:
        List();
        void print();
        bool isempty();
        void insert(unsigned long int time2,char action2, char PIcode2[12],char CDname2[51]);
        elem *first;
        elem *last;
};

void List::insert(unsigned long int time,char action, char PIcode[12],char CDname[51])
{
    elem *newptr=new elem(time,action,PIcode,CDname);

    if(isempty())
    {
        first=last=newptr;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next=newptr;
        last=newptr;
    }
}

}

bool List::isempty()
{
    return (first==NULL);
}

List::List()
{
    first=last=NULL;
}


bool checkCode(elem *iev, elem *iev2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<51;i++)
    {
        if(iev->CDname[i]!=iev2->CDname[i]) return false;
    }

return true;
}


int main()
{
fstream fin("cd_maina.i1",ios::in);
fstream fout("cd_maina.out",ios::out);

    unsigned long int time;
    char action;
    char PIcode[12];
    char CDname[51];

    List queue1;

    bool delete1=0;

    while(fin)
    {
        fin>>time;
        fin>>action;
        fin>>PIcode;
        fin>>CDname;

        queue1.insert(time,action,PIcode,CDname);
    }

    elem *glob=queue1.first;
    elem *cur;
    elem *cur2;

    while(glob!=NULL)
    {
        cur=glob;
        cur2=cur->next;
        delete1=0;

        while(cur2->next!=NULL)
        {

            if( ((cur->action=='A' && cur2->action=='B') || (cur->action=='B' && cur2->action=='A')) && checkCode(cur,cur2) )
            {
                if(cur->action=='A')
                {
                    fout<<cur2->time<<" ";
                    fout<<cur->PIcode<<" ";
                    fout<<cur2->PIcode<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    fout<<cur2->time<<" ";
                    fout<<cur2->PIcode<<" ";
                    fout<<cur->PIcode<<endl;
                }

                if(cur==queue1.first)
                {
                    queue1.first=cur->next;
                    glob=queue1.first;
                    delete cur;
                    delete1=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    elem *cur3=queue1.first;
                    while(cur3->next!=cur)
                    {
                        cur3=cur3->next;
                    }
                    if(cur==glob) glob=glob->next;
                    cur3->next=cur->next;
                    delete cur;
                    delete1=1;
                }

                if(cur2==queue1.last)
                {
                    elem *cur4=queue1.first;
                    while(cur4->next!=cur2)
                    {
                        cur4=cur4->next;
                    }
                    cur4->next=0;
                    queue1.last=cur4;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    elem *cur4=queue1.first;
                    while(cur4->next!=cur2)
                    {
                        cur4=cur4->next;
                    }
                    cur4->next=cur2->next;
                    delete cur2;
                    break;
                }
            }

            cur2=cur2->next;
        }

        if(delete1==0) glob=glob->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: "crashes immediately" -- did you try setting a breakpoint at the first line of `main` and stepping through to see what crashes?

Comment: "crashes immediately" is *probably* not what happens (although it is possible, if it crashes in one of the class constructors). Use a debugger, or sprinkle your code with `printf ("made it up to here!\n"); fflsuh(stdout);`.

Comment: @Jongware did sprinkle my code with printf `("made it up to here!\n");`, prints everything in main function and then drops an error that program has stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the initial part of your loop:

```
 while( glob != NULL ){
    cur = glob;
    cur2 = cur->next;   // <<<<<<<<<< cur2 is glob->next WHICH CAN BE NULL
    delete1 = 0;

    while(cur2->next != NULL) {       // dereference NULL
```

The program does not handle strings (CDname, PIcode) correctly.

Use std::string and std::deque.

Comment: now the program breaks on input examples like 
`100000 A 01010122222 CD1`
`100001 A 01010122222 CD1`
`100002 A 01010122222 CD1`
`100003 B 11111122222 CD1`
`100004 A 01010122222 CD1`
`100005 B 12121233333 CD1`
`100006 B 11111122222 CD1`
where multiple answers are correct.

Comment: Found out that the problem is many similar CDnames, something wrong with `bool checkcode()`.

Comment: It prints out 2 out of 3 pairs from example above and then crashes

Comment: At least, use strcmp(). You'll have to revise much of your program. Adam's comment is also valuable. - A linked list for containing both A and B isn't the best choice. Look into "map", one for A, one for B. And there may be several offers from different users. It's not so simple, but it can be made simple by using the right data structures!

Answer (score 0):

The crash seems to be caused by a [dangling-pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)!

In case of a match, cur may be deleted:

```
if(cur==queue1.first) {
    queue1.first=cur->next;
    glob=queue1.first;
    delete cur;
    delete1=1; }
```

Then, the in the next iteration of the loop "while(cur2->next!=NULL)", you use cur, the dangling pointer.

```
if( ((cur->action=='A' && cur2->action=='B') || (cur->action=='B' && cur2->action=='A')) && checkCode(cur,cur2) )
```

At this step, the cur may be already deleted and cause a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) and a crash!!

Advice:

- when using delete, set the pointer to NULL!
- when using a pointer that can be NULL, always check if it's NULL!